# Java Client extracting from Measurements

Tags: cumulocity

How can I extract from Measurements like

- c8y_MotionMeasurement
- c8y_AnalogMeasurement
- c8y_SignalStrength

the attributes with Java Client?
Example for c8y_MotionMeasurement content:

```
"c8y_MotionMeasurement":{
    "x":{
        "unit":"m/s^2",
        "value":0.046882
    },
    "y":{
        "unit":"m/s^2",
        "value":0.140647
    },
    "z":{
        "unit":"m/s^2",
        "value":0.984529
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at device-capability-model project.
It already includes a lot of commonly used fragments. If the fragments you need exist you can do something like this in java:

```
Measurement m = ... // get measurement from c8y
SignalStrength s = m.get(c8y.SignalStrength.class);
```

If the fragment does not exist in device-capability-model I would recommend creating a class for that fragment in your project. Of course you can always handle everything as a map and just get the fragment (as Object) by the key.

```
m.get("c8y_SignalStrength")
```